# Split at first line break into two different groups

Tags: regex

I have a likely simple regex task but can't seem to figure out the exact syntax.

I want to take a multi-line string (a Markdown document) and group the first line (the title) as one group and then all the subsequent lines in a second group.

```
# Title     // ] Group 1: Title
            // \
Some text.  // |
            // | Group 2: Content
# A heading // |
More text.  // /
```

Everything I try seems to either select everything within the first group (`(?s)([\S, ]*)\n(.*)`) or it splits group 2 apart into a bunch of groups of varying sizes.

I'm testing in [Expressions](http://www.apptorium.com/expressions) and ultimately implementing in JavaScript scripts as well as [Workflow's](https://workflow.is) Match Text action.

I'm still learning regex but while I've figured out other more complicated tasks this one is alluding me.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share one example of such multi-line string?

Comment: Care to leave any feedback on the solution? Did you give it a try? Did It work out?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply @Gurman, I posted this right before calling it a night. Here is [an example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63a36699a127a1755df8a4b3eec7f5d7)

Comment: No problem. I just tested the solution provided against your input string. It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will select and capture 1st line in Group 1 and the rest of the lines in group 2:

```
^(.*)\n([\s\S]*)
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8zE5Gg/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(.*)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline and store it in group 1
- `\n` - matches a newline
- `([\s\S]*)` - matches all the remaining characters including newlines and store it in group 2

Comment: That works perfectly and I appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Use a *reluctant* quantifier for the title:

```
(?s)(.*?)\n(.*)
```

or even simpler, move the DOTALL flag `(?s)` *after* the title:

```
(.*)\n(?s)(.*)
```

Comment: Both of those worked as well and I hadn't realized you could change the flag mid expression, that's awesome! Thank you!